# Quotient ring of a local ring

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

If $R$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $m$ and $I$ is an ideal, then if $R/I$ is a vector space over $R/m$? If it's not true, under what condition for the ideal $I$, do we have $R/I$ is a vector space over $R/m$?

Comment: Do you mean a vector space?

Comment: @Riquelme yes, I have fixed

Comment: Not in general.  For this to be true, the ideal $m$ of $R$ would have to act by the zero map via the natural action of $R$ on $R/I$.  But by considering the image of $1$, we see that this can only happen if $I = m$.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is true that $R/m$ is an $R/I$-module, but $R/I$ is not an $R/m$-module (=vector space because $R/m$ is a field).